# How many closed binary operations on A have x as the identity?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is this one example in my book that explains how to do this, but it's very obsecure and I just can't follow it.

It says if:

A = {x,a,b,c,d} then there are 5^16 closed binary operations on A that have x as the identity. How do we arrive at such an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $16$ ordered pairs $(s,t)$ where $s$ and $t$ range over the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$.  For each of these ordered pairs, we can choose arbitrarily which of $5$ values ($x,a,b,c,d$) our function will have at $(s,t)$.

The values of our function at ordered pairs of the form $(x, u)$ or $(u,x)$ are determined. Since $x$ is an identity, the function value at such an ordered pair is $u$.

Since we have $5$ choices at each of $16$ ordered pairs, there are $5^{16}$ possible choices, that is, $5^{16}$ binary operations on $A$ for which $x$ is an identity.

Comment: Can u explain how this relates to x being the identity?

Comment: I added a sentence. We do not have any choice about value of the operation (function) at ordered pairs that have an $x$ in them. I don't know what notation you use, probably $F(s,t)$ or $sFt$. We must have $F(x,u)=u$ and $F(u,x)=u$ for any $u$, because $x$ is an identity.

Comment: Why are we choosing values for the pairs?

Comment: In order to determine a binary operation $F$ on $A$, we must give the **value** of $F(s,t)$ for every one of the ordered pairs $(s,t)$. These values must be in $A$, so if there are no restrictions, and $A$ has $5$ elements, there are $5^2$ ordered pairs. At each we have $5$ choices, total $5^{25}$. However, in our case $x$ is supposed to be an identity, so we have no choice, for example, about $F(x,c)$. It must be $c$. But there are $16$ ordered pairs $(s,t)$ for which we have free choice, we can let $F(s,t)$ be any of $x,a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Since my book says there are 9 values where x is the first component and i am wondering what these 9 are.

Comment: That's not true, but there are $9$ ordered pairs for which $x$ is a component, not necessarily first. They are $(x,a), (x,b), (x,c), (x,d), (a,x), (b,x), (c,x), (d,x)$ and $(x,x)$,

Comment: Then shouldnt only those 9 be where x is the identity? Confused now. Because the other 5^16 dont have x in it or i just cant seem to see it.

Comment: The other $16$ ordered pairs $(s,t)$ don't have an $x$ in them,  so we can decide on the value of $F(s,t)$ arbitrarily for these.

Comment: Buf don't we only want pAirs with x in it

Comment: The pairs with an $x$ in them, like $(b,x)$, are places where we have **no choice**. Since $x$ is an identity, we are **forced** to make $F(b,x)=b$.  It is for ordered pairs $(s,t)$ that **don't** have an $x$ that we have freedom to decide what $F(s,t)$ will be, we have $5$ choices.

Comment: I got it now thanks1|!

Comment: You are welcome. It takes a while, the language used is strange and abstract. But after a while one can visualize, and things become easier. The main purpose of a lot of the exercises is to give you familiarity with the language.